# Sometimes pop-ups and contextmenus leave an "echo" in the user interface

Tags: gnome

Not sure how to explain this but the situtation is as follows.

Sometimes an application will throw a popup or a contextmenu. Then after I close that popup or menu and switch to a different application or workspace there is still an echo, a grey area where the popup or menu was. The only way to get rid of it is either to reproduce the graphical effect and hope it goes away properly this time or to close the owner of said popup or menu(so if Chrome made a popup and it leaves an echo it will only go away after closing all instance of Google Chrome).

Does anyone have a solution? I tried Googling but it's hard to Google for this sort of thing(that or my Google-fu is lacking).

I use Ubuntu 10.10 and Gnome 2.32.0.

Edit 29-07:

I included a screenshot. The effect is in the lower right corner.
[image]

Comment: please, add screenshot if it occurs again

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0):

I have two guesses. First, it might be that Compiz (the program in charge of graphical effects) is not refreshing the area where the animation occurred after the last frame. I have this happen all the time on my Desktop. What I do to get rid of it is to move the cube slightly (most any graphical effect the uses the whole screen should work). 
To test this, you could login using the classic Ubuntu interface, and then run `metacity --replace`. If it doesn't happen any more, this could be it.

Another thing it could be would be some drag and drop bug. In this case, you might not be able to click anything behind the grey area. Unfortunately, I'm not sure what you could do about that other than seeing if you can reproduce it and then reporting it.

Comment: I use Compiz but I don't use the cube, just plain workspaces. What does metacy --replace actually do?

Comment: @rbottel It runs a plain window manager that comes with gnome 2 that doesn't do the 3D stuff Compiz does. The --replace tells it to run in the place of compiz for this desktop session (or until you run compiz --replace)